# Problem with hierarchical facets on Shopify with Algolia's named_tags

Tags: shopify, algolia, shopify-app, instantsearch.js

I'm having issues with Algolia's instantsearch hierachicalmenu implementation on shopify. Every item on the list seems ok, but I couldn't get it working. Here is what I've done so far:

.
.
.

1. I have `<div class="hierarchical-categories-menu"></div>` in *snippets/algolia_instant_search.hogan.liquid*
2. I have following codes in *assets/algolia_instant_search.js.liquid*

```
  instant.search.addWidget(
      instantsearch.widgets.hierarchicalMenu({
         container: '.hierarchical-categories-menu',
         attributes: ['named_tags.lvl0', 'named_tags.lvl1', 'named_tags.lvl2', 'named_tags.lvl3'],
         autoHideContainer: false,
         showParentLevel: true,
      })
   );
```

3. I have lvl0, lvl1, lvl2, lvl3 facets as "**active**" and "**hidden**" on shopify-app's "**Search Options**" page.
4. Algolia's XHR response includes `results[0].facets.named_tags.lvl0 .. lvl3` nodes with values and counts correctly.
5. Algolia's XHR response includes `results[0].hits[n].named_tags.lvl0 .. lvl3` nodes.
6. Sample level data is as follows:
   `lvl0: "Žene"
   lvl1: "Žene > Odeća"
   lvl2: "Žene > Odeća > Gornji Delovi"
   lvl3: "Žene > Odeća > Gornji Delovi > Košulje"`

.
.
.

When I inspect the elements on the result page, I only see an **empty div** as the last child of .hierarchical-categories-menu:
`<div class="ais-hierarchical-menu--list ais-hierarchical-menu--list__lvl0"></div>`

Can anyone tell what the problem might be?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that you should make the "lvl" facets "**inactive**" on shopify-app's config page for some reason.